# What elements have their own keypress handlings?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a bit of code that starts with this:

```
 document.addEventListener('keyup',
                function (e) {
                    // I DO NOT WANT TO HANDLE INPUT FROM THESE
                    if (["INPUT", "SELECT", "TEXTAREA"].includes(e.target.tagName)) return;
                    //... do stuff with keypresses here
                });
```

This of course watches for the keyup event on the entire document, to fire special events when the enter key is pressed -- I use this for barcode scanning mostly, as my barcode scanner is set to input keys and then press ENTER.

So I've set it up so that it DOESN'T fire my special events when keys are pressed while focused in INPUT, SELECT, and TEXTAREA elements, because generally I'll want those to be handled in their own way.

Are there any other html elements that I should be aware of, that handle key events in their own way?

Comment: What about `<iframe>`?

Comment: oh good question, i'm not sure if I would need to handle that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is the [list of focusable elements](https://gist.github.com/jamiewilson/c3043f8c818b6b0ccffd):

> - HTMLInputElement
> - HTMLSelectElement
> - HTMLTextAreaElement
> - HTMLAnchorElement
> - HTMLButtonElement
> - HTMLAreaElement

Note that *Button* and *Anchor* can only listen to `enter` keypress, so you might not need this exception

Comment: That's brilliant. The way my app works, I definitely have to *consider* buttons, but I shouldn't treat them the same as Input, Textarea, etc. Your answer gave me the hint I need to tie it off - the final thing I need to do is to unfocus anchors and buttons when I'm detecting a barcode scan (but allow Enter to go through as normal when not).